# Android Jwebsocket custom protocol

Tags: android, websocket

I am opening a connection setting up a custom protocol like this:

```
WebSocketSubProtocol d = new WebSocketSubProtocol("MyCustomProto",WebSocketEncoding.TEXT);  
mJWC.addSubProtocol(d);  
mJWC.open(mURL);
```

But... Server side, I receive tis in the protocol string

> "org.jwebsocket.json MyCustomProto"

How can I remove from the string the "org.jwebsocket.json" ?
I don't wanna do it server side...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer to my own question.

By calling the "addSubProtocol" doesn't seem to be the right solution for couple of reasons:

if you call those 3 lines of code multiple time (if the first time the connection failed for example..) well the the protocol string would be something like

> "org.jwebsocket.json MyCustomProto MyCustomProto"

It just keep adding the protocol..

So I found a turn around. Now I don't use that "addSubProtocol" but instead I defined the protocol directly when I create the socket

```
mJWC = new BaseTokenClient("client||"+code+"||"+name,WebSocketEncoding.TEXT);
```

Voila.. Now no more "org.jwebsocket.json" anymore